# Python MongoDB query to get list of documents where '_id' != id

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have multiple documents in the collection. Document contains `_id` and `transaction_id`. In most of the documents, `_id` is same as `transaction_id`. I have to check if there is any document for a particular `transaction_id` has non matching `_id`. For this, I am using below app

```
all_trans_doc_list = list(tc_coll.find({}))    # Getting all docs from collection
for transaction_id in transaction_list:
    
    found = False
    for trans in all_trans_doc_list:
        if str(trans['_id']) == str(transaction_id ):
            found = False
        else:
            found = True
```

Problem with above approach is that, for ex I have transaction list as `[12345, 67890]`. So for transaction_id `[12345]` and `trans['_id']` matches, so found becomes False but for another `trans['_id']` it becomes True, so this approach is not correct. Can anyone please suggest a query which can list all the documents in which `_id` & `transaction_id` are not matching. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$expr` aggregation expression operator with `$ne` operator in your query to select not matching documents and its `transaction_id` in provided list of ids using `$in`,

```py
all_trans_doc_list = tc_coll.find({ 
  'transaction_id': { '$in': transaction_list },
  '$expr': { '$ne': ['$transaction_id', '$_id'] } 
})
```